# Openshift does not work with guzzle (using curl)

Tags: php, curl, openshift, guzzle

Hello fellows I have an application launched on openshift but I cannot get ti working with guzzle.

The application is on https://github.com/pc-magas/webtags
And you can visit it on http://webtag-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/

The problem I get is When I insert a website on the input field I get this following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in
>   /var/lib/openshift/57364a4c2d5271f0f500007b/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php
>   on line 78

On my personal computer works like a charm, the openshift is where I get the problem.

Do you know how I can make it working on openshift?

Comment: Are you running php earlier than 5.5.0 on openshift?

Comment: Yes I am running php 5.4

Comment: That's the problem, Guzzle 6 requires PHP 5.5 or greater, and the function [curl_reset](http://php.net/curl_reset) did not exist until 5.5

Comment: How do I install PHP 5.5 on openshift?

Comment: I don't know much about it.  I assume you have root access to a VM?  Check for that OS how to install a newer version of PHP (probably switching repos).  PHP 5.4 has been end of life for a while now so it makes sense to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openshift has php 5.4 that guzzle does not support